# html link to local file breaks after Microsoft Office Update

Tags: php

I have an intranet site that every time Microsoft does an update to office, the links to Microsoft Office filetypes break.

Message presented is:
Some files contain viruses that can be harmful...

Do you want to open this file?

Program: Microsoft Word (word,excel,does not matter)

Address: file:///\local server url path\filename.filetype?OR=ProtocolHandler&CID=.......

We have been seeing the message in google and edge. The ?OR=... is the oddity. I have opened two tickets with Microsoft Tech Support on the issue and they are clueless as to what is causing the issue.

I am running IIS on the server and the site is built on php. I have mapped a virtual directory to the internal share directory where the files are stored. And up until 4th quarter last year, everything worked perfectly fine.

One caviot to share. To allow staff to open the file and not download the file to their downloads folder, I had to add the following: `<a href= "ms-word:ofe|u|file:///server path/filename"></a>`

Has anyone else seen this? If so do you have a recommendation to try?

If I revert to previous versions of office it resolves the issue temporarily until another patch is pushed out. I have upgraded office from 2016 to 2021 but once an update runs, it breaks the link.

Comment: It turns out that office is choking on file:/// when I changed it to https:// it opens the file in read only mode. For 90% of the links I have on the intranet site, that is acceptable. For the few log files we have that individuals update, it would be preferable to open the document in standard mode. I am using "ms-word:ofe|u|" in front of the url. Any suggestions would be appreciated.